# Pie Chart jQuery-UI plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would greatly appreciate the input of any gurus out there. I have recently begun learning JavaScript and then jQuery and jQuery-UI and have thought I would take a stab at writing my own jQuery-UI plugin, the result of which you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ben1729/djA6G/ .

It's basically a pie chart into which you can drill down, rendered using HTML5 canvas. The data provided is dummy and so just oscillates between two data sets. I envisaged it displaying population of continents then by country upon drilldown etc.

What I'm after is constructive criticism. If there are any best practices I have violated or any obvious functionality I have missed then please let me know.

jQuery UI plugin:

```
(function($) {

// Utility object with helper functions
var utils = {
    tau: 2 * Math.PI,
    angleOrigin: -Math.PI / 2,
    sum: function(toSum) {
        var total = 0;
        $.each(toSum, function(n, value) {
            total += value;
        });
        return total;
    },
    normalise: function(toNormalise) {
        var total = utils.sum(toNormalise);
        var toReturn = [];
        $.each(toNormalise, function(n, value) {
            toReturn.push(utils.tau * value / total);
        });
        return toReturn;
    },
    distanceSqrd: function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        return Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2);
    },
    bearing: function(x, y, originX, originY) {
        var toReturn = Math.atan2(x - originX, originY - y);
        if (toReturn < 0) {
            toReturn += utils.tau;
        }
        return toReturn;
    },
    getIndex: function(bearing, dataArray) {
        var cumulativeAngle = 0;
        var toReturn = 0;
        $.each(dataArray, function(n, value) {
            cumulativeAngle += value;
            if (bearing < cumulativeAngle) {
                toReturn = n;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return toReturn;
    }
};

// Object for storing drawing functionality
var renderer = {
    clear: function(widget) {
        widget.context.clearRect(0, 0, widget.options.width, widget.options.height);
    },
    drawData: function(widget, opacity) {
        var startAngle = utils.angleOrigin;
        $.each(widget.dataArray, function(n, value) {
            var colour = widget.options.colourFn(n);
            renderer.drawSector(widget, colour, startAngle, startAngle + value, opacity);
            startAngle += value;
        });
    },
    drawSector: function(widget, colour, startAngle, endAngle, opacity) {
        var context = widget.context;

        context.globalAlpha = opacity || 1;
        context.fillStyle = colour;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(widget.centreX, widget.centreY);
        context.arc(widget.centreX, widget.centreY, widget.options.radius, startAngle, endAngle);
        context.lineTo(widget.centreX, widget.centreY);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        context.globalAlpha = 1;
    },
    // Based on current data, the selected segment will swallow the others then call the callback
    swallowOthers: function(widget, selectedIndex, callback) {
        var startAngle = utils.angleOrigin;
        $.each(widget.dataArray, function(n, value) {
            if (n === selectedIndex) {
                return false;
            } else {
                startAngle += value;
            }
        });
        var endAngle = startAngle + widget.dataArray[selectedIndex];
        var stepSize = (utils.tau - widget.dataArray[selectedIndex]) / 50;
        var colour = widget.options.colourFn(selectedIndex);
        var swallow = function() {
            if (endAngle - startAngle < utils.tau) {
                endAngle += stepSize;
                renderer.drawSector(widget, colour, startAngle, endAngle);
                setTimeout(swallow, 20);
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        };
        setTimeout(swallow, 20);
    },
    // The current data will fade in from the old colour then call the callback
    fadeInNewData: function(widget, oldColour, callback) {
        var opacity = 0;
        var fadeIn = function() {
            opacity += 0.02;
            if (opacity <= 1) {
                renderer.clear(widget);
                if (oldColour) {
                    renderer.drawSector(widget, oldColour, 0, utils.tau);
                }
                renderer.drawData(widget, opacity);
                setTimeout(fadeIn, 20);
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        };
        setTimeout(fadeIn, 20);
    },
    // Fade out the old data
    fadeOutOldData: function(widget, callback) {
        var opacity = 1;
        var fadeOut = function() {
            opacity -= 0.02;
            if (opacity >= 0) {
                renderer.clear(widget);
                renderer.drawData(widget, opacity);
                setTimeout(fadeOut, 20);
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        };
        setTimeout(fadeOut, 50);
    }
};

$.widget("ui.piChart", {

    canvas: null,
    $canvas: null,
    context: null,
    centreX: null,
    centreY: null,
    dataArray: null,
    isAnimating: false,
    radiusSqrd: null,
    hoverIndex: -1,

    // These options will be used as defaults
    options: {
        dataProvider: null,
        // Required
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        radius: 80,
        colourFn: function(selectedIndex) {
            var defaultRainbow = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'];
            return defaultRainbow[selectedIndex % defaultRainbow.length];
        },
        animationComplete: function(selectedIndex) {},
        mouseMove: function(hoverIndex) {}
    },

    // Set up the widget
    _create: function() {

        // Store reference to self
        var self = this;

        // Create HTML5 canvas
        this.canvas = $('<canvas>', {
            width: this.options.width,
            height: this.options.height
        }).attr('id', 'ui-piChart-canvas').appendTo(this.element[0])[0];
        this.canvas.width = this.options.width;
        this.canvas.height = this.options.height;
        this.$canvas = $(this.canvas);

        // Other useful variables to store
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.centreX = this.options.width / 2;
        this.centreY = this.options.height / 2;
        this.radiusSqrd = this.options.radius * this.options.radius;

        // Get current data
        this.dataArray = utils.normalise(this.options.dataProvider.getRoot());

        // Initial draw of the data
        renderer.clear(this);
        renderer.drawData(this);

        // Click event handler
        this.$canvas.click(function(event) {
            if (!self.isAnimating && utils.distanceSqrd(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, self.centreX, self.centreY) < self.radiusSqrd) {

                // Get the selected index based on the click location
                var bearing = utils.bearing(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, self.centreX, self.centreY);
                var selectedIndex = utils.getIndex(bearing, self.dataArray);

                // Check whether there is child data for the selected index
                if (self.options.dataProvider.hasChildren(selectedIndex)) {

                    // Start the animation
                    self.isAnimating = true;

                    // Store the previous colour for the purposes of fade in
                    var oldColour = self.options.colourFn(selectedIndex);

                    // First swallow the other segments
                    renderer.swallowOthers(self, selectedIndex, function() {

                        // Reset the data
                        self.dataArray = utils.normalise(self.options.dataProvider.getChildren(selectedIndex));

                        // Fade in the new data
                        renderer.fadeInNewData(self, oldColour, function() {

                            // Paint the pie chart for a final time
                            renderer.clear(self);
                            renderer.drawData(self);
                            self.options.animationComplete(selectedIndex);
                            self.isAnimating = false;
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        // Mousemove event
        this.$canvas.mousemove(function(event) {
            if (!self.isAnimating && utils.distanceSqrd(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, self.centreX, self.centreY) < self.radiusSqrd) {

                // Get the selected index based on the click location
                var bearing = utils.bearing(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, self.centreX, self.centreY);
                var selectedIndex = utils.getIndex(bearing, self.dataArray);

                if (selectedIndex !== self.hoverIndex) {
                    self.hoverIndex = selectedIndex;
                    self.options.mouseMove(self.hoverIndex);
                }
            }
        });
    },

    // Use the _setOption method to respond to changes to options
    _setOption: function(key, value) {

        // Store reference to self
        var self = this;

        switch (key) {
        case "data":
            if (!self.isAnimating) {
                // Start the animation
                self.isAnimating = true;

                // Redraw with new data
                renderer.fadeOutOldData(self, function() {
                    self.dataArray = utils.normalise(value);
                    renderer.clear(self);
                    renderer.fadeInNewData(self, null, function() {

                        // Paint the pie chart for a final time
                        renderer.clear(self);
                        renderer.drawData(self);
                        self.options.animationComplete(-1);
                        self.isAnimating = false;
                    });
                });
            }
            break;
            // TODO - Other options to set go here
        }

        // In jQuery UI 1.8, you have to manually invoke the _setOption method from the base widget
        $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    // Use the destroy method to clean up any modifications your widget has made to the DOM
    destroy: function() {
        $(this.canvas).remove();

        // In jQuery UI 1.8, you must invoke the destroy method from the base widget
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

The code being used by the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

// Dummy data provider which switches between two datasets
var dataProvider = (function() {
    var data1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 25];
    var data2 = [3, 3, 4, 5];
    var oddCalls = false;

    return {
        getRoot: function() {
            oddCalls = false;
            return data2;
        },
        getChildren: function(selectedIndex) {
            $('p#lastSelectedIndex').text('Selected index: ' + selectedIndex);
            oddCalls = (oddCalls === false);
            if (oddCalls) {
                return data1;
            } else {
                return data2;
            }
        },
        hasChildren: function(selectedIndex) {
            return true;
        }
    };
})();

// Create the pi chart
$('#create').click(function() {
    $('#canvasDiv').piChart({
        dataProvider: dataProvider,
        mouseMove: function(hoverIndex) {
            $('p#hoverIndex').text('Hover index: ' + hoverIndex);
        }
    });
    $('p#lastSelectedIndex').text('Root');
});

// Reset the dataset usin
$('#reset').click(function() {
    $('#canvasDiv').piChart('option', 'data', dataProvider.getRoot());
    $('p#lastSelectedIndex').text('Root');
    $('p#hoverIndex').text('');
});

// Destroy the pi chart
$('#destroy').click(function() {
    $('#canvasDiv').piChart('destroy');
    $('p#lastSelectedIndex').text('');
    $('p#hoverIndex').text('');
});

});​
</script>

<div id="canvasDiv"></div>

<button id="create">Create</button>

<button id="reset">Reset</button>

<button id="destroy">Destroy</button>

<p id="lastSelectedIndex"></p>

<p id="hoverIndex"></p>
```

Happy nit-picking!

Comment: Come on chaps. Anyone? Even if that you would not change anything (which I doubt - it cannot be perfect!) then I would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

There is a javascript concept about one `var` per scope.  Personally I'm not a big fan of it but you might want to read this: http://wonko.com/post/try-to-use-one-var-statement-per-scope-in-javascript